# Android ListView NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, listview, nullpointerexception

I am having problems populating the `ListView`. Logcat Shows `NullPointerExcepton`. I have also posted the code and logcat below.

The code was did in a hurry and I am just a beginner. So please point out any mistakes or suggestions.

```
package com.rj.unical;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class UnicalNotificationsActivity extends ListActivity {

       String notificationlinks[] = new String[100];
       String notificationnames[] = new String[100];
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


            //Create a list view 


        new DownloadNotificationTask().execute();

    }


    /////////////////////////
    private class DownloadNotificationTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute(){
            Toast.makeText(UnicalNotificationsActivity.this ,"Loading", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(UnicalNotificationsActivity.this,R.layout.exams,notificationnames);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
            ListView lv = getListView();

            //Set item click listener
            lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) {
                    //When an item is clicked, send the corresponding link to getResults class
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), getResults.class);       
                        i.putExtra("examlink", notificationlinks[(int)arg3]);
                        startActivity(i);

                    }

              });

        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            URL uni = null;
            try {
                uni = new URL("http://universityofcalicut.info/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=744&Itemid=324");
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            String url=uni.toString();
             Document doc = null;

                try {
                    doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
                 int index=-1;
                 int i=0;


                //Iterate every link and select only those with the string containing 202.88.252.6
                 for (Element link : links) {
                    index=-1;
                    index=link.attr("abs:href").indexOf(".pdf");

                    if(index!=-1 && link.attr("abs:href")!=null && link.text()!=null && link.text()!=" " && i<100)
                     {
                        //Store the link and corresponding names
                        notificationlinks[i]=link.attr("abs:href");
                        notificationnames[i]=link.text();

                        Log.d("PDF FOUND", notificationlinks[i]);
                     }
                   }
            return null;
        }



}

    ///////////////


}
```

here is the logcat

```
03-06 11:11:43.116: D/PDF FOUND(2626): http://universityofcalicut.info/notifications/CCSSUGIII120112.pdf
03-06 11:11:43.126: D/PDF FOUND(2626): http://universityofcalicut.info/notifications/NotfnIIIBAMS12112.pdf
03-06 11:11:43.137: D/PDF FOUND(2626): http://universityofcalicut.info/notifications/NotifnMomoeoThesis12112.pdf
03-06 11:11:43.166: D/PDF FOUND(2626): http://universityofcalicut.info/notifications/NotifnPGCCSS1stFolkloreExamchange10112.pdf
03-06 11:11:43.176: D/PDF FOUND(2626): http://universityofcalicut.info/notifications/NotiBA_POT_%20PvtRegn2012.pdf
03-06 11:11:43.196: D/PDF FOUND(2626): http://universityofcalicut.info/notifications/MEDexamchange020112.pdf
03-06 11:11:43.216: D/PDF FOUND(2626): http://universityofcalicut.info/notifications/afsaladibprefinal2012.pdf
03-06 11:11:43.236: D/AndroidRuntime(2626): Shutting down VM
03-06 11:11:43.236: W/dalvikvm(2626): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
03-06 11:11:43.256: E/AndroidRuntime(2626): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-06 11:11:43.256: E/AndroidRuntime(2626): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-06 11:11:43.256: E/AndroidRuntime(2626):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:355)
03-06 11:11:43.256: E/AndroidRuntime(2626):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
03-06 11:11:43.256: E/AndroidRuntime(2626):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1315)
03-06 11:11:43.256: E/AndroidRuntime(2626):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1727)
03-06 11:11:43.256: E/AndroidRuntime(2626):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:652)
03-06 11:11:43.256: E/AndroidRuntime(2626):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:709)
03-06 11:11:43.256: E/AndroidRuntime(2626):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1580)
03-06 11:11:43.256: E/AndroidRuntime(2626):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1147)
03-06 11:11:43.256: E/AndroidRuntime(2626):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
03-06 11:11:43.256: E/AndroidRuntime(2626):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
03-06 11:11:43.256: E/AndroidRuntime(2626):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
03-06 11:11:43.256: E/AndroidRuntime(2626):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
03-06 11:11:43.256: E/AndroidRuntime(2626):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
03-06 11:11:43.256: E/AndroidRuntime(2626):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
03-06 11:11:43.256: E/AndroidRuntime(2626):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
03-06 11:11:43.256: E/AndroidRuntime(2626):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1249)
03-06 11:11:43.256: E/AndroidRuntime(2626):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1125)
03-06 11:11:43.256: E/AndroidRuntime(2626):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1042)
03-06 11:11:43.256: E/AndroidRuntime(2626):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
03-06 11:11:43.256: E/AndroidRuntime(2626):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
03-06 11:11:43.256: E/AndroidRuntime(2626):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
03-06 11:11:43.256: E/AndroidRuntime(2626):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
03-06 11:11:43.256: E/AndroidRuntime(2626):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
03-06 11:11:43.256: E/AndroidRuntime(2626):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
03-06 11:11:43.256: E/AndroidRuntime(2626):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
03-06 11:11:43.256: E/AndroidRuntime(2626):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1045)
03-06 11:11:43.256: E/AndroidRuntime(2626):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
03-06 11:11:43.256: E/AndroidRuntime(2626):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-06 11:11:43.256: E/AndroidRuntime(2626):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-06 11:11:43.256: E/AndroidRuntime(2626):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-06 11:11:43.256: E/AndroidRuntime(2626):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-06 11:11:43.256: E/AndroidRuntime(2626):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-06 11:11:43.256: E/AndroidRuntime(2626):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-06 11:11:43.256: E/AndroidRuntime(2626):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-06 11:11:43.256: E/AndroidRuntime(2626):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you give a bit more colour as to what you're trying to do?

Comment: you have ArrayAdapter.java,then see line no.355

Comment: @Alex I am trying to get a set of links and corresponding text in to two string arrays,  notificationlinks and notificationnames, then display the notificationnames using a ListView lv. The links and the text is downloaded using an AsyncTask .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i have modified some quick code ..

there it may generate an error  if you tried to load the system contain View in some background thread

```
public class UnicalNotificationsActivity extends ListActivity {
    String notificationlinks[] = new String[100];
    String notificationnames[] = new String[100];
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Create a list view 
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(UnicalNotificationsActivity.this,R.layout.exams,notificationnames);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        ListView lv = getListView();

        //Set item click listener
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) {
                //When an item is clicked, send the corresponding link to getResults class
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), getResults.class);       
                i.putExtra("examlink", notificationlinks[(int)arg3]);
                startActivity(i);

            }

        });

        new DownloadNotificationTask().execute();
    }


    /////////////////////////
    private class DownloadNotificationTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
            protected void onPreExecute(){
            Toast.makeText(UnicalNotificationsActivity.this ,"Loading", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
        @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {


        }
        @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            URL uni = null;
            try {
                uni = new URL("http://universityofcalicut.info/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=744&Itemid=324");
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            String url=uni.toString();
            Document doc = null;

            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
            int index=-1;
            int i=0;

            //Iterate every link and select only those with the string containing 202.88.252.6
            for (Element link : links) {
                index=-1;
                index=link.attr("abs:href").indexOf(".pdf");

                if(index!=-1 && link.attr("abs:href")!=null && link.text()!=null && link.text()!=" " && i<100)
                {
                    //Store the link and corresponding names
                    notificationlinks[i]=link.attr("abs:href");
                    notificationnames[i]=link.text();

                    Log.d("PDF FOUND", notificationlinks[i]);
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
    ///////////////
}
```

Comment: but that makes the list to be created first and then start the async task, resulting in an empty list. It is the async task which downloads the strings in to notificationnames.

Comment: dont matter if list create a first ..you fill up adepter after list is created ..

Comment: not working. throws an uncaught exception.  I tried a Log.d() inside the doInBackground() but it didn't get logged. Does this mean that te running code is not entering the background function? onPreExecute works fine

Comment: i can't test it now as the website is not responding. Socket Time Out error. And that takes me o the next question. Is it possible to display a dialog saying "Network Error" and exit gracefully, instead of force closing the app. Or should i open a new question for this

Comment: u can get a result from the async task to  give the param 
<Void , Void , Boolean >  . boolean will give you the result of the your data

Comment: the code you have shown throws 'NullPointerException' . But when i insert it inside the 'onPostExecute', it works fine. Another problem i am facing is the 'Toast.makeText(UnicalNotificationsActivity,"Message",Toast.LENGTH_LONG);' does not work. neither does 'getApplicationContext()'

Comment: thanks for the help. finally got everything working. I forgot to add the show() to Toast.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not the correct approach.. because you are using an async task... which runs in different thread... and by the time it returns the result... the oncreate is executed...and the adapter is empty as async task has not returned any result yet... so it is giving you null pointer exception...

Comment: sorry. Found out the cause of NullPointerException. I wasn't incrementing the variable i. Stupid mistake really. Thanks for the reply.