# android listview gives nullpointerexception

Tags: android, android-listview

I have this `ListView`, when i launch the application it gives a null-pointer exception, but if the view is GONE, it doesn't give any error,

```
lVers = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lVers);
```

with the adapter

```
RechercheAdapter adapter2 = new RechercheAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.elem_recherche, listPaysVers);
lVers.setAdapter(adapter2);
```

here is the adapter class

```
public class RechercheAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Pays> {

        Context context;
        ArrayList<Pays> data;

        public RechercheAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Pays> d) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, d);
            this.data = d;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return data.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Pays getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return data.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            Pays p = data.get(position);

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.elem_recherche, null);

            ImageView drap = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.drap);
            drap.setImageDrawable(Utils.getBitmapFromBase64FullSize(p.getDreapeau64(), getActivity()));

            TextView nom = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nom);
            nom.setText(p.getPays());

            return convertView;
        }

    }
```

when I try to launch the application, I get a nullpointerexception,

```
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2467)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1775)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:678)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:739)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1628)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2300)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14072)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4607)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1644)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1428)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14072)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4607)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14072)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4607)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14072)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4607)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14072)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4607)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:948)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14072)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4607)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14072)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4607)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14072)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4607)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14072)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4607)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14072)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4607)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14072)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4607)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14072)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4607)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:948)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14072)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4607)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:948)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14072)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4607)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14072)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4607)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1655)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1513)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1426)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14072)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4607)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
09-24 12:52:37.095: E/AndroidRuntime(30836):
```

any one has a clue about what's going on ?
thanks

Comment: Post your `listview` object in xml

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9645383/android-listview-nullpointerexception

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Return View V not convertView or

```
   convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.elem_recherche, null);
```

Comment: thanks a lot!!! i was also stupid on mistake on set wrong layout xml and i check again in my code and it will help me.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this :

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.elem_recherche, null);
```

With :

```
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.elem_recherche, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem resides in your `getView(int, View, ViewGroup)` method:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ...
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.elem_recherche, null);
        ...
        return convertView;
    }
```

Note that you're returning `convertView`, and not `v` which is your inflated layout. `convertView` will be `null` as it's not initiated to a view, thus causing a `NullPointerException` upon access.

Try this instead:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Pays p = data.get(position);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if( convertView == null ) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.elem_recherche, null, false);
    }

    ImageView drap = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.drap);
    drap.setImageDrawable(Utils.getBitmapFromBase64FullSize(p.getDreapeau64(), getActivity()));

    TextView nom = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nom);
    nom.setText(p.getPays());

    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
public class RechercheAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Pays> {

        Context context;
        ArrayList<Pays> data;

        public RechercheAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Pays> d) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, d);
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            this.data = d;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return data.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Pays getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return data.get(position);
        }

@Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

          View view = convertView;
            Pays p = data.get(position);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.elem_recherche, null);

            ImageView drap = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.drap);
            drap.setImageDrawable(Utils.getBitmapFromBase64FullSize(p.getDreapeau64(), getActivity()));

            TextView nom = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.nom);
            nom.setText(p.getPays());

            return convertView;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are inflating one view and returning one view thats why it is null..
Change your getview metgod like this..

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Pays p = data.get(position);
if(convertView==null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.elem_recherche, null);
            ImageView drap = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.drap);
            TextView nom = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nom);
}  
         drap.setImageDrawable(Utils.getBitmapFromBase64FullSize(p.getDreapeau64(), getActivity()));
           nom.setText(p.getPays());

        return convertView;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use
`convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.elem_recherche, null);`
        instead of
`View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.elem_recherche, null);` then, return convertView;

Answer (score 1):

i think you have to give parent layout to which you are  going to inflate, because your list is created in parent Layout

```
  view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.elem_recherche, parent, false);
```